# Accessing Dictionary with Raw Input

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, dictionary, raw-input

I am trying to have a user input a 1,2,3,4,5,6.
Then have that integer align with a character name in my dictionary.

```
characters = {
'Stark': '1',
'Greyjoy': '2',
'California': '3',
'Whitewalkers': '4',
'Knights Watch': '5',
'Dalthraki': '6'
 }   

print 'Type 1 for Stark'
print 'Type 2 for Greyjoy'
print 'Type 3 for Lannister'
print 'Type 4 for Whitewalkers'
print 'Type 5 for Knights Watch'
print 'Type 6 for Dalthraki' 
choice = raw_input("> ")
if choice in characters:
    print 'You\'ve selected', choice 
else:
    splash()
```

I want to have my script print "You've selected Stark" after having the user input a 1.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Why don't you map numbers to character names?

Comment: Not that it matters at all for the question, but it is "[White Walkers](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/White_Walkers)", "[Night's Watch](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Night%27s_Watch)" and "[Dothraki](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dothraki)".

Comment: @F.J. Since the Dothraki don't have a native script I doubt they'll notice. :^)  user1598939: for bonus points, after you've inverted the dictionary, you can loop over the keys and values of the dictionary so you don't have to hardcode all those print statements.

Comment: @DSM I'll try another for loop for each row in the dict and have that printed on it's own without me printing each line. Thanks for the idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `dict` backwards:

```
characters = {
'1': 'Stark',
'2': 'Greyjoy',
'3': 'California',
'4': 'Whitewalkers',
'5': 'Knights Watch',
'6': 'Dalthraki',
}   

print 'Type 1 for Stark'
print 'Type 2 for Greyjoy'
print 'Type 3 for Lannister'
print 'Type 4 for Whitewalkers'
print 'Type 5 for Knights Watch'
print 'Type 6 for Dalthraki' 
choice = raw_input("> ")
if choice in characters:
    print 'You\'ve selected', characters[choice] 
else:
    pass
```

Comment: @user1598939 -- If this helped you, you should mark it as the accepted answer (click the little checkmark next to the answer).  That lets people know your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

change your dict to :

```
characters = {
'1':'Stark',
 '2':'Greyjoy',
'3':'California',
'4':'Whitewalkers',
'5':'Knights Watch',
'6':'Dalthraki'
 }
```

and use:

```
if choice in characters:
    print 'You\'ve selected {0}'.format(characters[choice])
else:
    splash()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really use a dictionary that way. You can reverse the key/value pairs and then use characters[choice] to get the name of the character. If you want to preserve the dictionary as is, your best bet is to iterate over the items

```
characterName = None
names = characters.items()
while characterName is None and names:
    if names[0][1] == choice:
        characterName = names[0][0]
    else:
        names = names[1:]
```

After running this, you'll either have a character name in characterName, or it will be None if the user made an invalid entry.

Comment: This needs a few edits, I think: it's not valid Python syntax, and has several other typos (chararacterName, items).  Even if you were searching this way, though, I think a for loop with a break, or a `next` call, would be much simpler.

Comment: Depends on personal preference I suppose. I don't like using a for loop unless I know I'm definitely going to iterate over every item.

Comment: @Skunkwaffle So if this game is a quick little 20 second script and the player would only select the character once, a for loop might not be the wisest choice?

Comment: If we're talking about performance, I don't think it would matter too much. But keeping in mind that "code is read more often than it is written", style and clarity of code are important, even in a simple situation like this. If you see a for loop with x iterations, you should be able to assume it's going to perform all x iterations, but that's unnecessary in this case since you only need to find the correct answer. Realistically though, unless you NEED the dictionary structured as originally posted, swapping the keys and values is by far the best solution.